# Rails 4: how to implement routes for a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

In our Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
        t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.date :date
        t.time :time
        t.string :focus
        t.string :format
        t.string :blog_title
        t.text :long_copy
        t.text :short_copy
        t.string :link
        t.string :hashtag
        t.string :media
        t.float :promotion
        t.string :target
        t.integer :approval
        t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The trick here is that we have a many-to-many relationship, with users having many calendars, and calendars having many users, both through the Administration join table.

We will need to display both:

- The list of calendars for a given user
- AND the list of users for a given calendar (from within the session of a given user, given that a user can only see the calendars that belong to him)

First, we thought of nesting the `resources` in the `routes` file, for instance this way:

```
resources :users do
  resources :administrations
  resources :calendars
end
```

But then we wondered whether we could also nest them the other way around, like so:

```
resources :calendars do
      resources :administrations
      resources :users
    end
```

Would that let us achieve what we need? Is this a good practice (or even something possible)?

If not, how should we structure our routes?

**UPDATE**: what about the following route structure:

```
resources :users do
  resources :administrations
end

resources :calendars do
  resources :administrations
end
```

Can we nest one resource into two different other resources?

Comment: This is a lot of questions wrapped up into one... perhaps you could break it up into discrete smaller questions to make it easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are perfectly right, sorry about that. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest one resource into two or more other resources using [Routing Concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns). For example:

```
concern :administratable do
  resources :administrations
end

resources :users, concerns: :administratable
resources :calendars, concerns: :administratable
```

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, this would let us setup routes such as `users/:user_id/administrations/:administration_id` and `calendars/:calendar_id/administrations/:administration_id`, right?

Comment: Also, with this code, are we supposed to remove `resources :users` and `resources :calendars` from the `routes` file? In other words, does the code you recommend replace the initial declaration of resources in the `routes` file or is it complementary to it?